# Share a WebView between activities

Tags: android, android-webview

I've written an iOS app that I want to port to android.  This app is a front-end for a web-based timekeeping system at work.  Unfortunately, the system doesn't have an API, so I'm screen-scraping it using xpath queries in javascript.  In iOS, I only have to load this page once because I get full control over when instances of my `UIWebView` get destroyed.

The iOS app only has 3 use cases, each which break into separate Android
activities:

- Login
- View a list of all reported times
- Report a new time.

Using a naive approach, my android views (including the `WebView` I need to use to interact with the timekeeping system) will be destroyed and recreated when I switch between views.  If I have to reload the `WebView` every time I switch activities, my app will appear very slow.

Is it possible to share a `WebView` instance between multiple
activities?  I know I can set the `launchMode` to `singleInstance`, but ideally, it would be nice to allow separate instances so that the back button would function normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per a [suggestion on from Eric Burke at STL Mobile Dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/stl-mobile-dev/FcXslhqGVVY/695XUiFYj8kJ):

> See if your Android `Application` can create the `WebView`. You won't actually display the `WebView` anywhere, it's just created for interaction with the web site. The `WebView` instance's lifecycle is then managed by your `Application` rather than an `Activity`.

I was able to share my `WebView` between my `Activity` instances.  I specified a custom `Application` in my manifest, and created the `WebView` inside the `Application`.  The `Application` is a `Context` and it lives as long as the app does, so all `Activity` objects can share the `WebView` that way.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the question so that it makes sense.  Clearly, we both think our respective answers are poor given context.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is little different. It pivots around couple of things.

1. WebViews can be created with application context.
2. There is something called MutableContextWrapper, we can flip the underlying context inside it.

So, we create the web view in the pool with mutable context wrapper with appContext and when an activity context asks for it, we flip the context and return it. We flip the context to appContext when we return the webView back.

Something like this

```
    // Has a single web view, and crashes if a request to obtain comes in and the
// cached instance is already allocated.
public class SingularWebViewPool implements WebViewPool {

    private WebView mCachedInstance;
    private volatile int mBorrower;
    private final int mSignature;
    private final Context mAppCtx;

    public SingularWebViewPool(Context appCtx) {
        this.mAppCtx = appCtx;
        this.mCachedInstance = new WebView(appCtx);
        // We will match this every time, we flip to app context to ensure a different web view is
        // not handed over to us.
        this.mSignature = mCachedInstance.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public WebView obtain(@NonNull Context activity) {
        if (mCachedInstance != null) {
            Context ctx = mCachedInstance.getContext();
            if (ctx instanceof MutableContextWrapper) {
                ((MutableContextWrapper) ctx).setBaseContext(activity);
            } else
                // We should not reach here!
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cached web view stored without a mutable context wrapper.");
            WebView temp = mCachedInstance;
            mCachedInstance = null;
            this.mBorrower = activity.hashCode();
            return temp;
        } else
            throw new IllegalStateException("Pool not having a cached web view instance when obtain() was called.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean release(@NonNull WebView webView, @NonNull Context borrower) {
        // Validate the last borrower.
        if (borrower.hashCode() != this.mBorrower) {
            return false;
        }
        Context ctx = webView.getContext();
      
        if (ctx instanceof MutableContextWrapper) {
            ((MutableContextWrapper) ctx).setBaseContext(mAppCtx);
        } else
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cached web view stored without a mutable context wrapper.");

        // match the signature.
        if (mSignature != mCachedInstance.hashCode()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("A different web view is released other than what we have given out.");
        }

        mCachedInstance = webView;
        mBorrower = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```